# Can't read NSUserDefaults data between views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Disclaimer: major noob

I'm writing an arithmetic flash card app as a learning project. I have a UITabViewController with the bottom tab bar that toggles between a few different views. Everything works okay until I try to set NSUserDefault boolean values in the Settings view controller and try to read those values in the Flashcards view controller.

The settings view has a switch to enable/disable each operator (addition, subtraction, etc) and the flashcard view should randomly present a flash card if that type of operation was enabled.

I believe that my mistake is that I don't understand the key concept of data encapsulation, objects, etc. I'd appreciate any help.

Here is the Settings view controller. I'm not even sure how to put the code into this forum so this might be a laughable moment... here goes:

```
//  settings_flashcards.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface settings_flashcards : UIViewController {
UISwitch *additionSwitch;
UISwitch *subtractionSwitch;
UISwitch *multiplicationSwitch;
UISwitch *divisionSwitch;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *additionSwitch;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *subtractionSwitch;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *multiplicationSwitch;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *divisionSwitch;

@end
```

and...

```
/  settings_flashcards.m

#import "settings_flashcards.h"

@implementation settings_flashcards

@synthesize additionSwitch;
@synthesize subtractionSwitch;
@synthesize multiplicationSwitch;
@synthesize divisionSwitch;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[additionSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(additionSwitchFlipped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[subtractionSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(subtractionSwitchFlipped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[multiplicationSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(multiplicationSwitchFlipped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[divisionSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(divisionSwitchFlipped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void) additionSwitchFlipped {
if (additionSwitch.on) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"additionKey"];
}else {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:FALSE forKey:@"additionKey"];
}
}

-(void) subtractionSwitchFlipped {
if (subtractionSwitch.on) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"subtractionKey"];  
}else {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:FALSE forKey:@"subtractionKey"]; 
}
}

-(void) multiplicationSwitchFlipped {
if (multiplicationSwitch.on) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"multiplicationKey"];   
}else {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:FALSE forKey:@"multiplicationKey"];  
}

}

-(void) divisionSwitchFlipped {
if (divisionSwitch.on) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"divisionKey"]; 
}else {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:FALSE forKey:@"divisionKey"];    
}
}
```

Here is the Flashcards view...

```
//  flashcardsViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface flashcardsViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>{

UILabel *firstNumberLabel;
UILabel *secondNumberLabel;
UILabel *answerNumberLabel;
UILabel *operatorLabel;

BOOL additionIsEnabled;
BOOL subtractionIsEnabled;
BOOL multiplicationIsEnabled;
BOOL divisionIsEnabled;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *firstNumberLabel;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *secondNumberLabel;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *answerNumberLabel;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *operatorLabel;

-(void) buttonClicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

and...

```
//  flashcardsViewController.m

#import "flashcardsViewController.h"

@implementation flashcardsViewController

@synthesize firstNumberLabel;
@synthesize secondNumberLabel;
@synthesize answerNumberLabel;
@synthesize operatorLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

srand(time(0)); //seed random

//the following should assign the keys if they don't exist  
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"additionKey"]){
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"additionKey"];
}   


if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"subtractionKey"]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"subtractionKey"];
}

if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"multiplicationKey"]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"multiplicationKey"];

}

if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"divisionKey"]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"divisionKey"];
}

//the following should assign each BOOL variable based on the key
additionIsEnabled = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"additionKey"];
subtractionIsEnabled = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"subtractionKey"];
multiplicationIsEnabled = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"multiplicationKey"];
divisionIsEnabled = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"divisionKey"];
[super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void) buttonClicked:(id)sender{

int a = rand() %  4;// random number generator (number to enter loop)   

if ( additionIsEnabled || subtractionIsEnabled || multiplicationIsEnabled || divisionIsEnabled) {
    while (a < 5) {
        switch (a) {
            case 0:
                if (additionIsEnabled == TRUE){
                    int x = rand() % 11 + 1;
                    int y = rand() %11 + 1;
                    firstNumberLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"%i",x];
                    secondNumberLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"%i",y];
                    answerNumberLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"%i",(x+y)];
                    operatorLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"+"];
                    a = 5;
                }
                else a++;
                break;
            case 1:
                if (subtractionIsEnabled == TRUE){
                    int x = rand() % 19 + 1;
                    int y = rand() %11 + 1;
                    firstNumberLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"%i",x];
                    secondNumberLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"%i",y];
                    answerNumberLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"%i",(x-y) ];
                    operatorLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"-"];
                    a = 5;
                }
                else a++;
                break;
            case 2:
                if (multiplicationIsEnabled == TRUE){
                    int x = rand() % 11 + 1;
                    int y = rand() %11 + 1;
                    firstNumberLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"%i",x];
                    secondNumberLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"%i",y];
                    answerNumberLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"%i",(x*y)];
                    operatorLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"×"];
                    a = 5;
                }
                else a++;
                break;
            case 3:
                if (divisionIsEnabled == TRUE){
                    int x = rand() % 11 + 1;
                    int y = rand() % 11 + 1;
                    firstNumberLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"%i",(x*y)];
                    secondNumberLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"%i",y];
                    answerNumberLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"%i",x];
                    operatorLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"÷"];
                    a = 5;
                }
                else a = 0;
                break;
                default:
                break;
        }
    }       
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *noOperatorSelectedAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"You have not set any operations."
                                                   message:@"Return to the settings menu and decide which operations you wish to perform. (addition, subtraction, etc.)"
                                                   delegate:self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [noOperatorSelectedAlert show];
    [noOperatorSelectedAlert release];
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]`? You could call this every time you set a new value.

Comment: @fabian: Calling `synchronize` is a bad mistake and should rarely be used.  All it does is create unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Do you really want to set all the settings to TRUE every time you load your view ? If you want to test whether they keys exist you should use `objectForKey:` instead which will return `nil` if the key doesn't exist. Also, in Objective-C, you normally use `YES` and `NO` instead of `TRUE` and `FALSE` (although the later should work as well).

Comment: @sudo rm -rf is right, you only need to call `synchronize` when going into background or resigning active.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things to do here. Firstly you want a better way of saying what the default state is before the user has made any explicit decisions. Next you want to know when you should refresh your in-app state from user preferences.

**Defaults Initialization**

The first item's solution is to put the default values into the *registration domain* for your user preferences. This is something you'll do during application initialization, rather than having your views individually check preferences and update them at initialization time. The preferences system looks in quite a few places for data, and the first place it looks is in the in-memory-only registration domain. This is where you'll put the default (i.e. no value specified means 'x') values for each of your user preferences.

The API you'll use for this is `-[NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:]`, which takes an `NSDictionary` of values. To set your default values of `YES` (in Objective-C the BOOL type uses `YES` and `NO` rather than `TRUE` and `FALSE`) you'll use something like this, commonly executed in a `+initialize` method for your application's main class:

```
+ (void) initialize
{
    // in any +initialize, make sure it's being called on your class
    // +initialize is different from all other methods in this respect
    if ( [self isKindOfClass: [MyApplicationDelegate class]] == NO )
        return;    // being called on a superclass, don't do my stuff

    // set up default values for certain preferences
    NSMutableDictionary * defaults = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [defaults setObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] forKey: @"additionKey"];
    [defaults setObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] forKey: @"subtractionKey"];
    [defaults setObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] forKey: @"multiplicationKey"];
    [defaults setObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] forKey: @"divisionKey"];

    // set this as the registration domain
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults: defaults];
    [defaults release];
}
```

Usually you'll put *everything* into one method like this, so if you have other parts of the application which expect a default non-zero value for any preference, you should add those to this group and place it into your application delegate's `+initialize` method.

Now, when your other classes use `[[NSUserDefault standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"additionKey"]` and there is nothing saved to the preference files for that key, they will get the value supplied above.

**Refreshing Cached Values**

So, you have a view where the user is able to change these preferences. Your next job is to make the view above that update its member variables using the new preferences. For this we can use either delegation or notification. In this case, I'll go with notifications for to reasons:

1. You're using NSUserDefaults, which can theoretically change in many different places. Delegation would only inform you of changes made by *one* object.
2. NSUserDefaults already implements a handy notification which you can watch.

So, in your flashcardsViewController you'll have something like these few methods:

```
- (void) updateFromPreferences
{
    // fetch current values from user defaults into your member variables
    additionIsEnabled = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"additionKey"];
    // etc...
}

- (void) viewWillLoad
{
    // load variables from user defaults
    [self updateFromPreferences];

    // find out when the preferences have been changed
    // this will cause -updateFromPreferences to be called
    // whenever something changes preferences, inside the app or outside
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultNotificationCenter] addObserver: self
                                                         selector: @selector(updateFromPreferences)
                                                             name: NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
                                                           object: nil];
}

- (void) viewDidUnload
{
    // always remove notification observers.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultNotificationCenter] removeObserver: self
                                                                name: NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
                                                              object: nil];
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    // add this to your existing dealloc routine
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultNotificationCenter] removeObserver: self
                                                                name: NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
                                                              object: nil];
}
```

**Summary**

Taken together, these two should give you everything you need to make this work.

Comment: Drat. My understanding of how the view controller thing works is that let's say I clicked on the Settings tab. Then Setting's viewDidLoad would run. Now let's say I clicked on the Flashcard tab. Then Setting's viewDidUnload would run and Flashcard's viewDidLoad would run. Clicking on Settings tab once again would force Flashcard's viewDidUnload to run and Setting's viewDidLoad to run. Is that wrong?

Comment: @Sam: yes, that is wrong. Views are loaded just before they appear for the first time, but they are only unloaded if necessary. Quite often, views will simply remain loaded for the lifetime of your application unless the device starts to run low on memory. The `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` methods, on the other hand, will be called every time your view cycles in and out.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the "always YES" problem pointed out by [Chiefly Izzy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121712/cant-read-nsuserdefaults-data-between-views/5121806#5121806), your `-buttonClicked:` method does not read new values from `NSUserDefaults`. These values are read (once) in `[flashcardsViewController viewDidLoad]`. If they are changed in settings, the change will not be detected in `flashCardsViewController` until the next time it is loaded (probably the next time the application is launched).

The simplest approach would be to move your code for reading the `IsEnabled` BOOL values into the `-buttonClicked` method, like so:

```
-(void) buttonClicked:(id)sender {

    // the following should assign each BOOL variable based on the key
    NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    additionIsEnabled = [defaults boolForKey:@"additionKey"];
    subtractionIsEnabled = [defaults boolForKey:@"subtractionKey"];
    multiplicationIsEnabled = [defaults boolForKey:@"multiplicationKey"];
    divisionIsEnabled = [defaults boolForKey:@"divisionKey"];

    int a = rand() %  4;
    if ( additionIsEnabled || subtractionIsEnabled ...
```

Answer (score 3):

This code ...

```
//the following should assign the keys if they don't exist  
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"additionKey"]){
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"additionKey"];
}
```

... simply always set's `additionKey` to `TRUE`. If you would like to check if `additionKey` is set, do this ...

```
//the following should assign the keys if they don't exist  
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"additionKey"]){
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"additionKey"];
}
```

... `boolForKey:` documentation: If a boolean value is associated with defaultName in the user defaults, that value is returned. Otherwise, NO is returned.

Translated to human language - if there's an value associated with `additionKey`, this value is returned. If there's no associated value, NO/FALSE is returned.

So, your code does this - if value is not associated with `additionKey` or if it is set to NO, set it to YES. This leads to this - `additionKey` is always set to YES/TRUE.